# Is there a way to make very close vertices from different objects move together when posing?

Tags: mesh, armature, vertices, pose-mode

I have part of a mesh that I separated to be its own object, but now when I move the bones in my armature I can see where the meshes split apart leaving a gap. This is an issue I didn't have before splitting the mesh.

Since both meshes have vertices still touching where the split happened, I'm wondering if there's any way to sort of make those touching vertices weld together so to speak, while keeping the objects as separate objects.

The reason I'm doing this is because I want to be able to swap out the limbs I separated for other ones to make a modular model.

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks!

Blender File: [image]

[image]

Comment: i think it should work if the vertices are assigned to the same vertex groups with the exact same weight, but maybe share your file (or this part of your object) so that we can test? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tips, follow up question: How can I make sure that they are assigned to the same group with the same weight?

Comment: you can do that with the N panel but maybe share your file?

Comment: I think that did it actually! Kind of a drag to do it for each vertex but it works, thanks so much!

Comment: I did put up the blend file though in case anyone comes up with a faster way to fixing this sort of thing though 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to separate the parts for some reason, you should have separate after parenting *With Automatic Weights* so that both the 2 edge loops (the one of the body and the one of the leg) are assigned to the same vertex groups with the same weights.

To fix the problem, first join the body to the legs (not sure why you've split the different parts but you can separate them again later), then in *Edit* mode select the body with <kbd>L</kbd> and move it upwards (on Z only) so that you can easily select the vertices that are on the edge loops on both parts, body and leg. Then select the edge loop of the body and remove from all groups:

[image]

Now, select one vertex of the body edge loops (1), shift select its corresponding body vertex (2), open the *N* panel and under *Vertex Weights* press the *Copy* button in order to assign the same vertex groups with the same weights to vertex 1:

[image]

Now move the body down until the vertices overlap, separate the body if you prefer to have separate pieces again (with <kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>P</kbd>), and move the bones to test, it sould work.

Another way: Once you've joined the parts, select the body edge loop, activate the *Snap to Vertex* and *Auto Merge* options, move the body edge loop until it snaps to the leg edge loop, deactivate the *Snap to Vertex* and *Auto Merge* options, press <kbd>V</kbd> to rip, now the body edge loop has the same weights as the leg edge loop.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed look! I still have to go through each vertex pair manually right? There's no way to sort of copy the weight from 1 look to another based on vertex proximity? The way that you can merge vertices by distance for example.

Comment: You could duplicate the body edge loop, and snap the leg edge loop to the body edge loop, the leg vertices will be replaced by the body ones, it's even faster than the solution I show, and maybe there are some other more elegant solutions. Actually if you've ripped the edge loop to create 2 parts, the 2 edge loops should be set the exact same way

Comment: Ah that makes sense, so if I merge the loops and then split them, they should have the same weights basically? That might be the best practice moving forward. I think I "broke" it when I re-calculated weights after splitting it, but I can re-merge them and then split them again.

Comment: Yes you can merge and separate, see my edit